# MIssing Number Treated as Zero in Subfigure

Tags: errors, subcaption

I know that this question has been asked multiple times here. But I am using *subcaption package*. But still it is giving the error. specifically I want 2 row and 2 column table of images.

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering % <-- added
    \begin{subfigure}[a]{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{one.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{two.pdf}
\end{subfigure} % <-- added

  \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{three.pdf}
\end{subfigure} % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}[d]{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{four.pdf}
\end{subfigure} % <-- added
\caption{Truncation of points}
\label{fig:images}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Are you adding subcaptions? If not, I don't think you need the `subfigure` environments.

Comment: Note that the optional argument to `subfigure` is for vertical alignment (same as a minipage), so the valid options are `t`(op), `c`(enter) and `b`(ottom). Edit: also, your snippet when added to a minimal document doesn't cause any errors, can you make a complete example?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. then how does the code look like Can you please write an answer

Comment: So you don't want subcaptions? Literally just remove all `\begin{subfigure}` and `\end{subfigure}`, so you have `\includegraphics{1} \includegraphics{2} <empty line> \includegraphics{3} \includegraphics{4}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. got it thanks :) can you just write that as an answer. So that I can accept

Comment: @TorbjørnT. what if I want simple a) and b) as subcaptions ?

Comment: I've asked you twice if wanted subcaptions ... Use the code you originally had, remove `[a]`, `[b]`, `[c]` and `[d]`, and add a `\caption{}` inside each `subfigure`. As I edited into my second comment, your code as is works fine for me (no errors), so we probably need a complete but minimal example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to figure out why you get the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're completely mis-using the optional argument of the `subfigure` environments. As it happens, the optional arguments `a`, and `d` are not valid and are thus simply ignored, `c` (short for "center") is the default and does nothing in the second row, and `b` (short for "bottom") is interpreted as requiring *bottom alignment* of the image with respect to the other items in the row (here: a single `subfigure` environment).

The three valid optional arguments of `subfigure` environments are the same as for `minipage` environments: `t` ("top"), `c` ("center"), and `b` ("bottom").

If you want to set dummy captions of the type `(a)`, `(b)` for each `subfigure`, just insert `\caption{}` directives inside each `subfigure`.

The following screenshot displays two `figure` environments. The first, with caption "Before", is based on your code, with red highlighting applied to the misplaced upper-right image. The second, with caption "After", gets rid of the `[a]`, `[b]`, etc optional arguments, uses four `\caption{}` directives, and arranges for a bit of horizontal and vertical visual separation of the images.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx,color}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}[a]{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{one.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.42\textwidth}
  \color{red}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{two.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{three.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[d]{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{four.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{Before}
\label{fig:images-before}
\end{figure}

\bigskip
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{one.pdf}
  \caption{} % <-- new
  \end{subfigure}%
  \qquad % <-- new
  \begin{subfigure}{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{two.pdf}
  \caption{} % <-- new
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip % <-- new
  \begin{subfigure}{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{three.pdf}
  \caption{} % <-- new
  \end{subfigure}%
  \qquad % <-- new
  \begin{subfigure}{0.42\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{four.pdf}
  \caption{} % <-- new
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{After}
\label{fig:images-after}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Got It . Thanks so much :) cleared the errror